# Do complex linear automorphisms always allow a basis of orthogonal eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to understand why the following lemma, given without proof in an article (and a reference which does not seem to answer it at all) holds:

**Lemma:** If $f \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ has an algebraically simple real eigenvalue $\rho$ such that for all other eigenvalues $\lambda \in \text{spec}(f)$ we have $|\lambda| < \rho$ and if $y$ is an eigenvector of $\rho$ and if $\mathbb{C}^n = \mathbb{C}y \oplus W$ with $f(W) = W$, then for $x = \alpha y + w$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $w \in W$ we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\rho^n} f^n x = \alpha y.$$

**My attempts:** We have

$$\frac{1}{\rho^n}f^nx = \frac{\alpha}{\rho^n}f^n y + \frac{1}{\rho^n}f^nw = \alpha y + \frac{1}{\rho^n}f^n w.$$

This converges to $\alpha y$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\rho^n}f^n w = 0$. This is for example true in the case that $f$ allows a basis of orthogonal eigenvectors, since then $\|f^nw\| \leq |\rho'|^n \cdot \|w\|$, where $\rho'$ is an eigenvalue such that $|\rho'|$ has the second biggest size among all eigenvectors. Then as $\left( \frac{\rho'}{\rho} \right)^{n} \to 0$ we are done. This leads to the following question:

**Question:** Do complex linear automorphisms always allow a basis of orthogonal eigenvectors?

I also have a second question (sorry, linear algebra was a long time ago...):

**Question:** Does a subspace $W$ as in the Lemma always exist if $f$ has an algebraically simple eigenvalue $\rho$ such that all other eigenvalues have smaller absolute value?

It would also be nice if you knew references.

Best regards,

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, complex operators do not necessarily have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors nor even a non-orthnormal basis of eigenvectors. In fact, an operator will have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors if and only if it is normal (this is the context of the [complex spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)).

However, a useful replacement for orthogonal diagonalizability which also solves your problem is given by the [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of an operator. Let $f \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an operator with an algebraically simple, real, positive eigenvalue $\rho > 0$ and denote the other eigenvalues of $f$ by $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$. You are given that $|\lambda_i| < \rho$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$. Denote by $V_{\rho}, V_{\lambda_1}, \dots, V_{\lambda_k}$ the [generalized eigenspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) of $f$. We always have a direct sum decomposition

$$ \mathbb{C}^n = V_{\rho} \oplus V_{\lambda_1} \oplus \dots \oplus V_{\lambda_k} $$

and each generalized eigenspace is $f$-invariant. In addition, since $\rho$ is algebraically simple, we have $\dim V_{\rho} = 1$ (and this is a true eigenspace). Hence, if you set $W = V_{\lambda_1} \oplus \dots V_{\lambda_k}$ and choose a non-zero vector $y \in V_{\rho}$ you get a direct sum decomposition $\mathbb{C}^n = \mathbb{C}y \oplus W$ with $f(W) \subseteq W$. If $f$ is invertible (equivalently, if $|\lambda_i| > 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$) then $f(W) = W$.

Next, given $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, decompose it as $x = \alpha y + w$ where $w \in W$ and then

$$ \frac{f^k(x)}{\rho^k} = \alpha y + \frac{f^k(w)}{\rho^k}. $$

Like you noted, to show that this goes to $\alpha y$ as $k \to \infty$, it is enough to show that $\frac{f^k(w)}{\rho^k} \to 0$. The Jordan normal form tells us that we can write $f|_{W} = S + N$ where $S \colon W \rightarrow W$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ and $N$ is nilpotent such that $SN = NS$. Since $\dim W = n - 1$, we have $N^{n-1} = 0$. Hence by the binomial theorem (using $NS = SN$) we have

$$ f^k(w) = (S + N)^k(w) = \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n - 1} {k \choose i} S^{k - i} N^i \right)(w) = \\
 S^k(w) + {k \choose 1} S^{k-1}(Nw) + \dots + {k \choose n - 1} S^{k - n + 1}(N^{n-1}(w)).$$

Finally, show that ${k \choose r} \frac{S^k(w')}{\rho^k} \to 0$ for all $r$ and $w' \in W$ using the fact that $S$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues of modulus less than $\rho$ by choosing a basis of eigenvectors of $S$ of $W$ and apply this to each of the $n$ summands above.